# Can SiteCollection include sub SiteCollection in SharePoint2013 / SharePoint2013 Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

All, I knew I can create `Site Collection` in `SharePoint 2013 Online`, and I can create `Sub Site` in the `Site Collection`. But I want to know if can create a sub `Site Collection` under the `Site Collection`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept of "sub Site Collection" in Sharepoint.
You can create sub site in a site collection, and under that sub site you can also create another subsite. You can create Nested sites under one sub site.

I can explain better if you provide a example what you want to achieve with this sub site collection.

Comment: Thanks your answer, It does help me understand .Forgive me it is just a newbie question.